# How to list MySQL Server closed connections?

Tags: mysql

To list active connections we do:

```
show processlist;
```

What to do to list old closed connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your [logging is enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) you can check them - you'll see at what time who/from where connected and later - when give connection was closed. eg:

```
100822 10:07:43   53514 Connect     ocs@localhost on
                  53514 Init DB     ocsweb
                  53514 Query       SELECT ... FROM ...
                  53514 Quit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
How much can this affect the performance of mysqld? My version is 5.0.18

Comment: @mmonem - it's a performance hit for sure and besides cpu load - it puts additional pressure on io subsystem. i guess you should try and see...